# InsertItemsAtIndexPaths doesn't update anything in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I try to add a new `UICollectionViewCell` in my `UICollectionView` but nothing is updated : I have a ViewController in which I update the dataArray for the datasource of my `UICollectionView` :

```
//update data before insert
    [(NSMutableArray *)_previousVC.projectsView.carousel.projectsData addObject:paramsRequest];
    _previousVC.hasBeenUpdatedFromProjectView = YES;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
```

The object is well added to my dataArray.

After poping viewController, in the previous viewController I use the `viewDidAppear` method to animate the cell which will be insert :

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    if(_hasBeenUpdatedFromProjectView == YES){
        NSInteger rowsAmount = [self.projectsView.carousel numberOfItemsInSection:0] -1;
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowsAmount inSection:0];
        NSArray * indexPathArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
        [self.projectsView.carousel insertItemsAtIndexPaths: indexPathArray];
    }
}
```

But when the viewcontroller appears, my UICollectionView hasn't been updated. Any idea ?

Comment: just ttry to reload collectionview.

Comment: Basically the index of where you have inserted your data object must match the indexPath parameter that you are using in the `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` call.

Comment: That method should call the reload method automatically.

Comment: reload method doesn't animate anything

Comment: Really @pe60t0 ? I didn't know, I will look at this.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work ? Do you get an error ? Can you verify that before calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` your data contains an additional element in the required position ?

Comment: No error but same result : nothing is updated : I have tried to insert object at the end on my data array by using addObject method of my dataArray. And then I have passed this index to the insert method but no result. And my data contains the new additional element before calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths yes.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to be sure check `indexPath` correct. And run it on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathArray];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
});
```

Hope this could help.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` is being executed on the main thread - no need to do a async call here